# How to set QUERY formula in Google Sheets with multiple criteria across multiple sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have 3 sheet name 'alex', 'shawn' and 'taki'.ALL had the same column but different row number

at new sheet (dashboard), where I want the query to show for column A to F but with criteria at col L = NOT 'case closed' and col A = date range (that I put at c23 and e23)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=QUERY({alex!A:Z; shawn!A:Z; taki!A:Z}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 
  where not Col12 = 'case closed' 
    and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(C23, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(E23, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```

Comment: hi @player0 not working, can the format of date "dd-mm-yyyy"?

Comment: not rly. format yyyy-mm-dd is mandatory for query to understand that is [dealing with dates](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/). can you share a copy/dummy of your sheet?